# What IDE to use for developing in Ruby on Rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Ruby IDE do you prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer)

I've generally been doing stuff on Microsoft .NET out of college almost 2 years ago. I just started looking at Ruby on Rails. So what editor should I use? I'm using [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) right now but can I get debugging etc. somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try both NetBeans and RadRails for maybe a week each, then you can find which works best for you.  The best advice is to learn your tool.  If you are not checking out something new about your editor, something that could potentially save you time (regexp, etc) then you are doing yourself a huge disservice.

I have been using Eclipse/Aptana/RadRails and unlike Gaius have been pretty happy with it.
I recommend the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers from Eclipse Downloads: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Then grab Aptana Studio, following these [instructions](http://www.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Plugging_Aptana_into_an_existing_Eclipse_configuration#Eclipse_3.4_Instructions).

When Eclipse restarts Aptana will have a view, click on rad rails and you are good to go.  Just make sure you have ruby installed already, or it becomes a pain to resolve.

Comment: Didn't Oracle nix the Rails support from NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, as of NetBeans 7.0 it won't be available officially

Answer (score 6):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)

I use it for all web development - HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, Rails...

EDIT: For full disclosure, I'm biased toward Aptana and RadRails as I know a few members of the original RadRails dev team.

Answer (score 5):

rubyMine is the most full featured IDE for Rails at the current time (2012).

Personally, for rails development I had used Eclipe for several months and then netBeans for several weeks and rubyMine is clearly better than them.

It's great in all the areas that count - code views, search and replace, source control management, testing, debugging and it's got features like viewing a model dependency diagram that are really neat.

It isn't free - cost about $50-$100.  This has recently become a key *positive* criteria for me.  Too many "free" products that I invest thousands of hours getting proficient in eventually die and stop being developed but paid products pay for continued development.  I've become weary of investing a lot of time and energy into such products only to have them wither and die.  Given the hundreds of thousands of dollars one earns from rails development a $100 tool is a bargain.

Despite how much I love rubyMine I still use vim along side it.  Sometimes my tasks works better with vim, sometimes with rubyMine.

Answer (score 3):

I've been very happy with [E](http://e-texteditor.com/). It's pretty lightweight and supports TextMate snippets and commands, which means you get access to a huge set of Rails-specific helpers.

However, it is decidedly an editor and not an IDE, so you won't get debugging, built in console, etc. But I've found that for Rails projects I prefer a light editor and a shell (like [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)) for tests, debugging, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Aptana/Eclipse/RadRails, but if I were to do it again, I'd definitely try NetBeans.  Aptana has been a major headache.

I've never used IronRuby, but that might make you feel more at home.

Answer (score 2):

The Netbeans IDE is a good, all around editor for many languages.  I'm pretty sure the 6.5 beta has support for Ruby on Rails, along with Javascript and a few other web languages.  It's worth checking out [(Netbeans.org)](http://www.netbeans.org).

Comment: Netbeans 5.5 had rails support.

Answer (score 1):

[Sapphire in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/) integrates with Visual Studio.

Comment: Today (Oct 6) a free version was released

Answer (score 0):

I mainly code ColdFusion or PHP (and JS/CSS/xHTML), but have dabbled in a bit of RoR. RadRails/Apatana has been great for me, because it's built on Eclipse, which I was already using for my other work. It also integrates with Subversion via the Subclipse plugin.

The Eclipse platform is so extensible that it's worth investing a bit of time in to learn, but then again I like having a single IDE rather than having to switch between different apps.

I briefly looked at Netbeans, but TBH Eclipse just felt better for me, and Aptana itself is great when you come to do anything in JavaScript.

YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

I use Emacs on Windows.

Installing and configuring it to work with rails is a pain though.

Answer (score 0):

I found Geany to be a lightweight alternative (which works on linux as well with little modification), although I am checking out Gedit for features that not present or implemented as well in Geany.