# What Ruby IDE do you prefer?

Tags: ruby, ide, editor

I've been using Eclipse with RDT (not RadRails) a lot lately, and I'm quite happy with it, but I'm wondering if you guys know any decent alternatives. I know NetBeans also supports Ruby these days, but I'm not sure what it has to offer over Eclipse.

Please, list any features you think are brilliant or useful when suggesting an IDE, makes it easier to compare.

Also, I said Ruby, not Rails. While Rails support is a plus, I prefer things to be none Rails-centric. It should also be available on Linux and optionally Solaris.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)? It's based on Eclipse and they have a sweet [Rails](http://www.aptana.com/rails) plugin.

Comment: Aptana seems to be the best IDE for Ruby, but I hate how it changes all my key mappings for the various editors (e.g., they remap <ctrl>-1 in the Java editor), and I hate how it writes databases in whatever directory I happen to be in when I start the IDE.  Yuck.  They're obviously not eating their own dog food.

Comment: Aptana sucks. It tells me that common english words are spelt wrong and gives me pointless warnings.

Comment: In the preferences you can disable the spell checker and warnings that don't apply to your language.

Comment: I tend to use Aptana exclusively for PHP/Ruby development, and standard Eclipse for JAVA, C, C++ etc. This prevents me from dealing with pointless warnings.

Comment: Slow and frequently crashes or puts out weird error messages on Ubuntu. Pretty sure it's not just me -- I've given it many many a chance over the years on a OS X and a variety of linuxes.

Answer (score 76):

[RubyMine](http://jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) from JetBrains. (Also available as a plugin to [IntelliJ IDEA](http://jetbrains.com/idea/index.html))

Comment: I expected to love RubyMine as I'm a big time Resharper user when in C# but the quality was way lower than I expected. Key features like the debugger, refactoring, intellisense were very buggy. So I'd definitely suggest trying the evaluation verson just to make sure you aren't let down.

Comment: I've been using RubyMine for 2+ years now for all my development and it beats everything else out there hands down. When I see how some of my friends and colleagues struggle with Textmate or VIM, just because they dislike IDE's, but all the same can't run the debugger effectively nor easily browse the sources of any gem, then I wonder what gives.
I've learned a ton just by having single keystroke access to any method definition in any gem. Jetbrains has managed to stay on top of it for the entire time and no sign of slowing down.

Answer (score 26):

[Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/) has been getting some attention lately, as well. Still early in its life, but it shows promise.

Comment: Redcar has the advantage of being written in Ruby, allowing Ruby developers to extend their editor using the same language. It's early days so it's not feature rich, but it's a decent IDE getting better.

Comment: redcar is great. :) It kinda sucks having to boot it from CLI, and keep another console window open, but whatever.

Comment: was pleasantly surprised to find how far along Redcar has come since the last time I tried it

Answer (score 23):

On Mac OS X, [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is a godsend.

Comment: Although TextMate is great text editor, people should educate themselves on the concept of IDE...

Comment: if textmate had autocompletion for ruby, I would use it for sure.

Answer (score 19):

The latest Netbeans IDE (6.1) has a pretty solid Ruby support.

You can check it out [here](http://www.netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html).

Comment: NetBeans has been coming along nicely and their Ruby and JRuby support is top-notch. Version 6.9.1 is the current as of this comment, with 6.10 on the way. Check out the live code coverage feature!

Comment: Unfortunately, Ruby support is discontinued for NetBeans 7. http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html

Comment: I used NetBeans for Ruby development for about a year. It actually wasn't too bad, though it had and still has some rough edges. (E.g. the way to set up keyboard shortcuts is needlessly laborious and confusing.) Oracle has stopped work on the Ruby module, but you can still use it if you download NetBeans 6.9.1. RubyMine is a lot better though.

Comment: It's back! The JRuby guys have picked up support for NetBeans - see [Ruby on NetBeans lives!](http://blog.enebo.com/2011/02/ruby-on-netbeans-lives.html) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 13):

Once I found Geany (Ubuntu), I switched from TextMate (OSX) and never looked back. 
Geany is a lean, clean, speedy IDE that can be used either as a text editor or a light-weight IDE. It supports not only text editing features (syntax highlighting, code folding, auto-completion, auto-closing, symbol lists, code navigation, directory tree, multi-tabbed open files etc.) but also normal IDE features such as simple project management, compile-build-run within the main window. Unlike TextMate, it has a Terminal screen within its own window; you do not have to go back and force between your editor window and terminal window. Unlike TextMate, it supports international languages. Unlike TextMate, it supports multi-platforms, Unlike TextMate, it is open-source and free. Geany is now my favorite C/Ruby/XML development tool.

Comment: I am seriously considering this as my primary IDE for Rails development on linux. Can anyone get me up to speed on any intellisense and inline documentation (e.g. showing the relevant API doc as on hover tooltip) features it may support currently?

Answer (score 10):

RubyMine is so awesome. Everything just works. I could go on and on. Code completion is fast, smooth, and accurate. Formatting is instantaneous. Project navigation is easy and without struggle. You can pop open any file with a few keystrokes. You don't even need to keep the project tree open, but it's there if you want. You can configure just about any aspect of it to behave exactly how you want.

NetBeans, Eclipse, and RubyMine all have more or less the same set of features. However, RubyMine is just so much more cleanly designed and easy to use. There's nothing awkward or clunky about it. There are all these nice little design touches that show how JetBrains really put thought into it instead of just amassing a big pile of features.

Incidentally RubyMine can do a lot of the things that Vim can do like select and edit a column of text or split the view into several editing panels with different files in them.

Answer (score 7):

[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) has some really solid Ruby support.

Answer (score 6):

I have used [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/index.mhtml) and it's pretty good. I use [TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate) now.

Answer (score 5):

For very simple Linux support if you like TextMate, try just gedit loaded with the right plugins.  Easy to set up and really customizable, I use it for just about everything.  There's also a lot of talk about emacs plugins if you're already using that normally.

Gedit: [How to set up like TextMate](http://crepuscular-homunculus.blogspot.com/2007/10/gedit-for-ruby-and-everything-else-on.html)

Answer (score 5):

In last 3 months, I have tried RadRails, Netbeans and RubyMine and finally settled on [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) not so much for features but for responsiveness and stability reasons.

In terms of features, RubyMine has slightly better `code completion`, `debugging` and `code navigation`, but only ruby beginners(like myself) need them most. `Relying on code completion and code navigation is anti-ruby/rails`, as ruby/rails names are supposed to be natural and each line of code needs to be in its convention determined location.

Comment: When I tried RubyMine it couldn't go more than a few minutes without crashing and opening any file was sure to crash it. Not impressed.

Comment: Both 2.0.2 and 3.0 beta(v 97.73) are good, at least on Windows 7 Professional with 4GB RAM. The one beta version before 97.73 use to hang after 10-15 minutes use. Which version did you try?

Comment: I'm using RubyMine 3.1 on OS X with no problems. I've also used other versions on Linux with no stability issues. Could there be some problem with your development system?

Answer (score 4):

[NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) is good because you can use it on Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: **Oracle** declared the end of **Ruby** in _NetBeans_. Too lame

Comment: @anyulled but i still find the ruby plugin for netbeans 7. I am not sure if it will work with 7.1 or 7.1.2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Most IDEs present the project structure in a top down manner. This is great way to explore at a high level when joining an existing project. However, after working on the same project for more than a year, I realized that this approach can become counter-productive.

After Oracle declared the end of Ruby in NetBeans, I switched to Vim. By using a command line and an editor as the only tools, I was forced to mentally switch to a bottom-up perspective. To my amazement, I discovered that this made me more focused and productive. As a bonus, I got first class HAML and SASS syntax support.

I recommend Vim + [Rails plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) for anyone that will work on a single project for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 4):

While TextMate is not an IDE in the classical sense, try the following in terminal to be 'wowed'

```
cd 'your-shiny-ruby-project'
mate .
```

It'll spawn up TextMate and the project drawer will list the contents of your project.  Pretty awesome if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

Aptana more or less is RadRails, or it's based on it. I've used it, and it's really good, but it does have some problems. For instance, it breaks the basic search dialog on my system (giving a raw java exception to the end user), and it clutters the interface with add like notices and upgrade bars and news feeds and...

But all in all it's pretty good, especially its editors (ERB, HTML/XML, ...) are top notch.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer TextMate on OS X. But Netbeans (multi-platform) is coming along quite nicely. Plus it comes with its IDE fully functional debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Textmate on osx

Answer (score 2):

[E Text Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_Text_Editor) is great ([TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate) compatible sort-of-clone for Windows).

Comment: his requirements include linux support. you can get e running in wine, but that is sort of meh.

Comment: I think e-texteditor now runs on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I started out using gEdit (ubuntu user), but even with all the plugins and modifications (class/file browser, terminal, darkmate scheme, etc, etc) it still always seemed to come up short. I've also tried like hell to get Aptana RadRails and Studio to work, but none of them ever really seemed to sync up with my workflow. I've even tried using Eclipse, but again, it just didn't work for me.

RubyMine also seemed like it would be great, but I found it to be way too buggy, even after the upgrade to 3.0.

So far, my favorite Ruby editor is [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit).  It's got syntax highlighting and can detect errors and recognize your code based on user-specified ruby versions.  Syntax highlighting schema are easily customizable and easy on the eyes.  There are some very nice plugins for git, it can have split-screen editors (love that feature), and a great file-browser. I really wish Komodo had built-in terminal (multiple terminal) support, but everything else about it I've really come to love, and haven't found anything better yet.

Answer (score 2):

[emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [ruby-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyMode), [rdebug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/rdebug-emacs.html) and a ruby interactive inferior shell.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for TextMate on Mac OS X.

See also answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064/what-ide-to-use-for-developing-in-ruby-on-rails-on-windows#16086).  I [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064/what-ide-to-use-for-developing-in-ruby-on-rails-on-windows#16086) trying [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend NetBeans 6.1 too. Very nice IDE and makes working with Ruby a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

I started out with RadRails then moved to Aptana when they took it over, wasn't too bad.  Got a macbook and have been using Textmate, never going back.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby in Steel: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/Ruby-In-Steel-Developer-Overview

A Visual Studio based Ruby IDE.  Fast Debugger. Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS there is also XCode.   http://developer.apple.com/tools/developonrailsleopard.html

Comment: any iOS developers out there who use xcode for ruby stuff and can provide some feedback on it's usefulness?