# Does any one know good editor available in RoR for windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Does any one know good editor available in RoR for windows?

Comment: Check this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html)

Comment: I have used NetBeans for several years now, and I think that it does an outstanding job on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you fancy an IDE, there is [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (Through the [RadRails](http://radrails.org/) plugin I believe), [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html)*. If you want a more Textmate-ish kind, there is [E-Texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) *, [Notepad ++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). There is also VIM or EMACS, I think. I don't have a windows machine, so I can't verify that, but how could there not be.

I've hand some experience, on the mac side, with the IDEs available. But, I find them very "heavy". This could be because I'm on a Mac, so you might get a better experience with those since your on Windows. I'm think it has do with the way each OS supports JVM.

*Must pay for these, at least last time I checked.