# Good and free Ruby editor for Windows?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Ruby IDE do you prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer)

What's a good and free Ruby editor for Windows? Thanks!

Comment: Unless it's closed, should it be made community wiki?

Answer (score 6):

Get yourself [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) it's an excellent lightweight text editor which is useful for lots of languages including ruby. There's tonnes of [plugins too](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/). I recommend you get the 'explorer' plugin which gives you a dockable directory explorer.

Answer (score 5):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) is Free and Good

Comment: I dont like Netbeans his intellisense is the slowest i ever saw !

Comment: Oracle has bought Sun and therefore netbeans, and Oracle said that dynamic languages (Ruby, Python, PHP) are "going to be supported by the community" i.e. not by Oracle. Therefore Ruby support on netbeans may be uncertain.

Comment: As uncertain as emacs and vi!

Comment: The Ruby plugin doesn't work in Netbeans 7.4.  There was a note about a hack to shoe horn it in, alas that didn't work on my installation.

Comment: today, I was able to get the "Ruby and Rails" plugin to work on Netbeans 8.2 it wasn't a huge amount of fuss, see the comments for that plugin here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails#comm

Answer (score 5):

don't be a wimp, use emacs.

Comment: Emacs is a good option on Linux not on windows ... On Windows use Notepad++.

Comment: Emacs works fine on Windows. For those of us with the Emacs key sequences programmed into our fingers, it's the only way to edit code when stuck on that platform.

Comment: emacs, notepad++, scite, ... all editors they don't stretch to the IDE level.

Answer (score 2):

[RubyMine 2](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) is not free (88 Euros) but it's clearly the best Ruby IDE i've ever used!

Answer (score 2):

[Aptana RADRails](http://www.radrails.org) is eclipse tunned for ruby and rails.
It's free too.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs would be good if he asked for an OS. Now go get gvim.

Comment: No processes or scheduler, no filesystems, no device drivers, no security model, memory protection, paging, multitasking, ... what exactly does Emacs have in common with an OS?

Answer (score 0):

SciTE isn't a bad editor. Did you get it with ruby?