# Apart from SCITE can anyone recommend a good tool for programming Ruby

Tags: ruby, scite

I have used SCITE for a few weeks now, wondered if there was an better alternative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://devver.net/blog/2008/10/ruby-tools-roundup/) covers a set of tools for programming in Ruby. They are not all ide's, it also compares profiling tools and test quality tools.

Comment: Brilliant Benny, nice one for this.

Comment: Dead link, but the Wayback Machine has it: http://web.archive.org/web/20091117132720/http://devver.net/blog/2008/10/ruby-tools-roundup/ Doesn't look like any of those are IDEs, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Textmate](http://macromates.com/) is the editor of choice if you are on a Mac

If you are on Windows [e text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) is a Textmate clone.

Otherwise you can check [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/text-editors)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/projects/ruby/) have good support of the Ruby language.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/).
On Mac, I use Textmate.