# mono or RoR for new application run on linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mono

I have little experience with ruby itself. I am going to hire somebody to write a web based application and I wanted it to be written in RoR but I was recommend mono. I guess because they like mono and because they think the RoR is slow.

The whole application would be some kind of social media meta management tool. There will be front end web based part and then back end doing the 'real stuff'.

I have no experience with mono at all and I am not experienced enough to comfortably say that RoR is the best choice.

I understood that if RoR is configured properly it could be pretty fast. I read that RoR has some troubles with scalability. I will start the application small and if it's successful I need to scale it up.

### What would you recommend?

in the light of

- performance
- scalability
- easiness to test
- easiness to maintain, develop code/project

( I like ruby but I am not going to be the developer myself. I prefer to choose the 'better' option if there is such answer to that question)

**please feel free to suggest anything else ...**

Comment: If you are more comfortable with Ruby and have never used Mono, theres no reason to get yourself tied with up with Mono and its Microsoft influence.

Comment: I like ruby and never used mono but I am not going to be the developer. I prefer to go with the 'better' option if there is such answer....

Comment: @Radek Hi, I know it has been a while since you asked this question. But which one did you choose and why? Thanks.

Comment: We were going to use RoR because of the developer's choice but at the end the project wasn't approved ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not going to write it yourself, you may want to go with what the person who will write it is most comfortable with.

Full disclosure: I have developed several sites now using Mono and I love it.  I have used Ruby-on-Rails but not for anything nearly as big as what I have done in Mono.  Keep that in mind.

Quick answer: In the greater scheme of things, Ruby-on-Rails and ASP.NET MVC have more in common than not.  My choice would be ASP.NET MVC on Mono but I doubt you would regret choosing either.

**Architecture:** If you want one way of doing it out of the box, choose Ruby-on-Rails.  If you want to be able to choose what you feel are the best-of-the-best technologies from a range of choices, choose .NET (Mono).

Ruby-on-Rails is more of a turn-key solution in that it provides a standard way of doing pretty much everything you need out of the box.  .NET (Mono) offers a lot more power (my opinion let's say) but there are a lot of different pieces to choose from and you have to choose a technology stack yourself.  As an example, RoR has a standard way of accessing databases while .NET Mono let/force you to choose from a dozen different ways to do that.

Mono and .NET generally have a little better separation of concerns so the purist in you might like that.  If not, you actually find the roll-up-your sleeves and get it done attitude of Ruby more to your liking.

**Performance and Scalability:** This should clearly go to .NET and Mono.  In fact, I believe the fastest way to run Ruby-on-Rails is to use IronRuby to run it on .NET.  StackOverflow is written in ASP.NET MVC and, given the amount of traffic, it obviously performs great.  Proof is in the pudding. That said, the performance bottleneck will probably not be your choice of framework.

**Testing:** Old style ASP.NET (now called WebForms) is considered pretty hard to test.  The newer ASP.NET MVC was designed to be easy to test and is similar to RoR.  One major factor is that in Mono you will probably be using a statically typed language (like C#) while Ruby is of course a dynamically typed language.  You have to write more tests in a dynamic language (because the compiler/interpreter will not catch type problems) but it can also be easier to write tests if you are not fighting the compiler.  I think it is a matter of taste and style (I like static) but this is a major factor in answering this question.

Of course, since .NET/Mono is a multi-language platform, you could always write your ASP.NET MVC tests in a dynamic language.  You could even do it in Ruby (IronRuby).  Perhaps that would be the best of both worlds (static checking on your real code and flexible dynamism in your tests).  I have considered doing this myself using IronPython for tests.

**Maintenance and development:** This is a tough one.  It depends what you are writing, what third-party libraries you might need, and what tools you are going to use.  I would say that RoR is probably the more advanced MVC framework.  My own thoughts are that Ruby-on-Rails is probably a shade easier to write but a little bit harder to maintain.

**Community:** I like the Ruby community more than the .NET one but I think I like the Mono one the best.  That makes it a little confusing.  The core Mono guys (like Michael Hutchinson that answered here) are simply awesome.  I really like MonoDevelop as a tool (IDE) as well.  It just keeps getting better and better.  Michael, thank you for Git support if you had anything to do with that.  :-)

**Tools:** If you are writing for Mono you can use the whole universe of .NET tools (VisualStudio, ReSharper, Reflector, etc) so that is pretty hard to beat.  That is assuming you develop on Windows of course.  On Linux or Mac the tool of choice for Mono would be MonoDevelop.  It supports version control, a software debugger, and NUnit tests right in the IDE and is completely cross-platform.

It seems like a lot of Ruby folks just use a simple text editor.  This may just be because an IDE just does not have as much to offer a dynamic language as it does a static one.  Here is a SO question on what people like for Ruby:

[What Ruby IDE do you prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer)

EDIT: Just to make things confusing...there is another MVC framework for .NET/Mono that is even more like Ruby-on-Rails; [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/) even has an implementation of ActiveRecord.  MonoRail has actually been around longer than ASP.NET MVC but I would stick with ASP.NET MVC these days as that is where the future lies.  ASP.NET MVC is open source by the way and ships with Mono out of the box (the actual Microsoft code).

Comment: What is the webserver to use for running Mono on .NET?

Comment: I would say the most common way to run Mono (.NET) on Linux is to use mod_mono with Apache.  That is what I have always done.  You can also use things like NGINX or Cherokee which I have been meaning to try.  In development, you can also use a simple webserver that ships with Mono called XSP2.  XSP2 is built into MonoDevelop so you can use a pretty similar development style to VisualStudio.

Comment: @jpartogi - I realize that I may have misunderstood your question.  Mono is just a .NET work-alike.  If you are running on Windows, your best bet is really to use IIS.  You can run Mono on Windows but there is really no reason not to just use .NET in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I can speak more to Rails than Mono.  RoR is pretty scalable these days with all of the cloud hosting services available.  Web applications query data and render web pages using that data, which really isn't that big of a deal.  Most performance issues are caused by database and schema design issues, not the web framework.  Typically, database response times dwarf other portions of server processing.  RoR is also very easy to test.  Testing is a more natural part of development than in other languages that I use.  When I started RoR programming I was used to the much more structured world of Java, and the more dynamic Rails won me over for web development.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I work on MonoDevelop, a crossplatform IDE for Mono (including ASP.NET & ASP.NET MVC), so feel free to consider my answer biased, but hopefully it will be helpful anyway.

**Performance**: a decent JIT compiler (Mono) should be much faster than an interpreter (Ruby). But it depends on the programmer's skill too - well-written Ruby *could* be faster than really badly written C#. The libraries and database and caching mechanisms you use will be a big factor too, but these aren't fundamental to the languages/frameworks.

**Scalability**: AFAIK there is no magic bullet for web app scalability, and although I don't have practical experience in this field, here's some info I've picked up. It really depends on your database usage, how your session state is stored, and how caching is implemented. This isn't really fundamental to either framework - once you start scaling to multiple machines, you'll probably have many machines/processes for database servers, cache servers, message queues, frontends, servers for static content, etc. Likely only the frontends will be ASP.NET or ROR, and if they're stateless, you can simply clone them and handle the scalability problems on the backend.

**Testing**: I can't speak for Ruby, but ASP.NET MVC (but not vanilla ASP.NET) was designed to be easily testable using .NET testing tools such as NUnit (Mono's own unit tests use NUnit).

**Maintenance and development**: Again, I can't really speak for Ruby, but it's pretty much a given that it will be easiest to develop (at least initially) in the language & framework that the developer already has experience with. Also, .NET has some amazing development tools on Windows - Visual Studio, ReSharper, etc. - and there's a huge pool of experienced C# and ASP.NET developers you can hire, though few of them will know Linux/Mono.

Also, StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC :)

Answer (score 3):

There are of course a [dizzying array of choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller&oldid=489968162#Implementations_as_web-based_frameworks) but another nice alternative is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).

It is basically Ruby-on-Rails for Python so most of the comparisons of RoR vs. ASP.NET MVC would apply.  Depending on what kind of site you are building, the really interesting feature of Django is the automatic admin interface.

Answer (score 3):

To introduce a little levity...

How about [DOS on Dope: the last MVC web framework you will ever need](http://www.secretgeek.net/dod_intro.asp)?

Comment: And to continue the series: [Bash on Balls](https://github.com/jayferd/balls) - API Driven Development (ADD)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be up and running quickly, I would go for RoR. Scaling rails is becoming easier with time and you have a big range of ruby runtime environments to choose from MRI 1.8, 1.9, REE 1.8, JRuby (run on java VM), Rubinius.

ASP.NET MVC is nice, but I still think it has some way to go before it offers the same speed of development as RoR.