# Advanced search in texteditor over whole project

Tags: ruby, regex, editor, sublimetext2, textmate

I'm looking for a way to do searches over all files in a project (ruby) like

- search for all class methods (they could begin with `def self.`, but also be nested inside a `class << self`)
- search for class instance variables (`@foobar` defined at class level)
- search for instance variables (`@foobar` defined on instance level)

Is this possible in any editor? I'm using textmate and sublime but haven't seen any advanced searches like this. I know regex would be a starting point, but most of the time it's a time consuming, "I'm not sure if it really works" issue.

Comment: some of best editor you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible in any editor?

Yes. For example, take a look at Emacs with Robe: https://github.com/dgutov/robe

Comment: looks interesting, but unfortunately only for Emacs. When I find another solution, I'll post it here