# a string output is not showing ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I'm tried these ruby code lines to run in **sublimeText3** but I dont get any error even in **view ->show console**. Show result shows me that the coding is building, but I couldn't see any output there. The below code is what I'm trying.

guess.rb

```
words = ['foobar', 'baz', 'quux']
secret = words[rand(3)]

print "guess? "
while guess = STDIN.gets
  guess.chop!
  if guess == secret
    puts "You win!"
    break
  else
    puts "Sorry, you lose."
  end
  print "guess? "
end
puts "The word was ", secret, "."
```

Comment: whats not working?, your program is working fine in my pc.

Comment: you tried ruby guess.rb?

Comment: I couldn't see the results in the build session in sublimetext3

Comment: Most text editors don't support interactive sessions, you have to run it from the terminal.

Comment: ok, let me try from my command prompt

Comment: is there any error in my code, have you got the guess == secret session after few tries. If yes, please tell me a best editor for ruby

Comment: there is no wrong in your code, try all the 3 values.

Comment: its working,so  "NO IDE" for ruby right

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer)

Comment: thanks @sravan, i have downloaded that IDE already but I haven't installed it let me check that for you

Comment: okay, carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Sublime Text console does not accept any input, you need to install package like [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL). You can launch it from *Tools > SublimeREPL > Ruby*.

Comment: I have installed that package into the sublimetext3 folder but still Im unable to see the launch session you said

Comment: What do you mean by “installed into the Sublime Text folder”? Package Control is the recommended way to install packages, just follow the steps described in [instructions](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#installation).

Comment: Im getting this error in tools -> SublimeREPL, `to_specs': Could not find 'pry' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Well, just install Pry then: `sudo gem install pry`. You should probably make your Ruby homework before diving deep into it.

Comment: I get a new error after insatlling pry gem, `<main>': uninitialized constant Pry::InputCompleter (NameError)

Comment: You should probably start a new question for your new problem

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/336) on GitHub, installing these version will fix your NameError